# Create a Google Worksheet from custom template containing App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

In my enterprise (company) Google Workspace, I created a Google worksheet template that I submitted to the Template Gallery.
The sheet contains an Apps Script and a Trigger for user edit. The script verifies if a specific checkbox gets checked, calls an external API (which cannot be done with simple triggers), and then updates a particular column.

The goal is for users (non-programmers) to create a new sheet from that template, ready to be used without any further (manual) configuration.

However, when I create a new worksheet from that template, the script is contained in the new sheet, but the Trigger is not. In addition, I have to run the script manually the first time to review the permissions for it to access my data and to connect to external services.

Therefore, whenever a user creates a new sheet from that template, I should perform (manually) the following steps for the script to work:

1. Create a Trigger in Apps Script
2. Run the script manually and review the permissions

I searched Google's Admin console for any settings for Apps Script, sheets, or security, but I couldn't find anything either.

I searched Google's documentation and Q&A forums for a similar issue, But I couldn't find an answer to my problem. The answers I always get describe how to create a template with Apps Script, or how to create a sheet with Apps Script.

Since this is a company's workspace, and since non-programmers will use the sheet, I expect the following whenever a user creates a new sheet from that template:

1. ✅ The new sheet contains the app script (currently this is the case)
2. ❌ The new sheet contains the Trigger (see image below) on user edit. Currently, the new sheet doesn't contain any triggers and I must add them manually.
   [image]
3. ❌ The script in the new sheet should be executed without the need of running it manually the first time to review permissions.
   [image]

Comment: You will have to create a script that creates the trigger for the user and the user will have to authenticate the process.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing. Now I have an onOpen simple trigger that checks if a trigger exists and, if not, creates it. However, the function fails due to a lack of permissions (the needed scopes are added in the manifest). As you said, the user will have to authenticate the process. But is there a way for the user to do it without open Apps Script? The only way I found until now is to run the script manually so that Google asks to review authorization.

Comment: i find that in similar situations the simplest thing is for the admin to be the OWNER of the new sheet made from the template, and the user to be a shared editor. that helps with permission issues.